# How to make an image animation effect like Apple.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, animation

Here is the demo:

http://www.apple.com/ipad/smart-cover/

The Apple smart-cover demo can drag and showcase how the smart-cover works. How does Apple do that? What is the idea behind? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be Done with jQuery. I went ahead and did it on jsfiddle and used the images from apple.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ynKnS/7/

Comment: @vbence i forgot to close the img tag properly. It is working in chrome now. http://jsfiddle.net/ynKnS/4/

Answer (score 6):

They are using lots of JPG files. For example:

http://movies.apple.com/media/us/ipad/2011/spin/smart_cover_sequence_20110302/ipad_unfold-053.jpg

http://movies.apple.com/media/us/ipad/2011/spin/smart_cover_sequence_20110302/ipad_unfold-054.jpg

...

They are 35-40 kByte each.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Jquery script that produces this effect, it's called Reel

http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel